# Running cy.request on beforeEach

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to set up on my cypress framework a way to, on every test scenario, execute some actions, among them a cy.request.

My `beforeEach.js` file is somewhere along these lines:

```
import { Actor, Action } from "cypress-screenplay";
import * as auth from "../../../../../support/ui/auth";

new Actor().perform(auth.uiLogin);
```

(the Actor object ultimately executes a cy.request) to perform a log in via API).

Then with the simplest test, I get the following message:

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Cannot call cy.request() outside a running test.

This usually happens when you accidentally write commands outside an it(...) test.

If that is the case, just move these commands inside an it(...) test.
```

How else can I solve this problem?

I do not want to include the contents of the beforeEach on another step of my cucumber test as it would add quite a lot of noise (one line per test, on 100 tests...)

Answer (score 1):

`beforeEach()` is a hook - a function call - not a file. In `/cypress/support/index.js` add

```js
import { Actor, Action } from "cypress-screenplay";
import * as auth from "./ui/auth";  

beforeEach(() => {
  new Actor().perform(auth.uiLogin)
})
```

This will run your login before every test.

One problem though, the usage for screenplay shows

```js
const actor = new Actor();
```

at the top of the test, and the actor logged in should be the same actor tested.

You can perhaps use a custom command instead,

**/cypress/support/index.js**

```js
import { Actor, Action } from "cypress-screenplay";
import * as auth from "./ui/auth";  

Cypress.Commands.add('loginNewActor', () => {
  const actor = new Actor()
  actor.perform(auth.uiLogin)
  return actor
})
```

**test**

```js
let actor

beforeEach(() => {
  actor = cy.loginNewActor()
})
```